# How to select all from array1 which contains the id from array2?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq statement which includes a Contain() method.  I am using this so that I can select all from an array where name is not null but only select the objects from the array1 that contains the same name in object array2.

I have managed to return the result but its displaying true or false where as I need the object values.

The code

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FamilyNames>(result);
List<object> data = new List<object>();

ClassName className = new ClassName();

object [] getNames = className.GetType()
     .GetProperties()
     .Select(p =>
       {
         object value = p.Name;
         return value == null ? null : value.ToString();
       })
         .ToArray();

foreach (var obj in response.items.Where(n => n.name != null).DistinctBy(x => x.name).Select(a => getNames.Contains(a.initialName)))
{
     data.Add(obj);
}
client.Dispose();
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The result is :

```
["True","False","True"]
```

If I don't use the select statement then I get my objects:

```
[
  {
    "initalName": "BD",
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "LastName": "Dilan"
  },
  {
    "initalName": "HT",
    "firstName": "Harry", // the initialName doesn't exist in list so need to remove this object
    "LastName": "Thomas"
  },
  {
    "initalName": "LJ",
    "firstName": "Lindsey",
    "LastName": "Jones"
  }
]
```

The initalName is not present in getNames array so needs to be removed. Any advice would be much appreciated, especially on the approach. The desired result would be:

```
[
      {
        "initalName": "BD",
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Dilan"
      },
      {
        "initalName": "LJ",
        "firstName": "Lindsey",
        "LastName": "Jones"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that in this LINQ expression, at the end you are selecting a Bool as an output. (.Contains() returns a bool).
From this reason, your expression will retunr a list of Bool.

```
response.items
.Where(n => n.name != null)
.DistinctBy(x => x.name)
.Select(a => getNames.Contains(a.initialName))
```

To acheave what you want, simply replace the .Select() with a .Where(), what will do the intended filtering and keep the original objects as they are, (will not do any projection) and you will get the expected outcome:

```
response.items
.Where(n => n.name != null)
.DistinctBy(x => x.name)
.Where(a => getNames.Contains(a.initialName))
```

Comment: Oh dear I feel very silly now, thank you kindly for the explanation :)

Comment: The only silly question is, what is not asked! Your wellcome!